# Typescript generated script works on plunkr but not my local

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-grid

Here is  [generated javascript](http://plnkr.co/edit/XkLd3uffOdFaFx1rujS0?p=preview) working on plunkr perfectly

But it does not works(click me button does nothing on my local)

Here is code:

typescript file:

```
module canling.controllers {  

    export interface IMyStoksScope extends ng.IScope {
        gridOptions: any;
        gridApi: any;    
        showMe();       
    }

    export class StoksController {
        private $scope: IMyStoksScope

        constructor($scope: IMyStoksScope) {
            this.$scope = $scope
            this.$scope.gridOptions = {}
            this.$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
                { name: 'id' },
                { name: 'stokAdi' }, {
                    name: 'view',
                    cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.showMe()">Click Me</button>'
                }]
            this.$scope.gridOptions.data = [{ id: 1, stokAdi: "one" }, { id: 2, stokAdi: "two" }]
            this.$scope.showMe = function () {
                alert(1)
            }
        }
    }
    StoksController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module("canling").controller('StoksController', StoksController);
}
```

---

```
module canling {
    export class Config {
        constructor($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
                .when("/stoks", { templateUrl: "/app/views/stoks/stoks.html",       controller: "StoksController" })
        }
    }
    Config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
}
```

---

```
((): void=> {
    var app = angular.module("canling", ['ngRoute', 'ui.grid' ]);
    app.config(canling.Config);
})()
```

---

and view is :

```
<button ng-click="showMe()">view entry</button>
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

`view entry` button clicks works by the way.

Anyone has any idea why `click me` on the grid does nothing on local?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The difference is coming from the  `ui-grid-unstable.js` version is used.

**on my locale**:

```
/*! ui-grid - v3.0.0-RC.18-d9b2314 - 2015-01-06
* Copyright (c) 2015 ; License: MIT */
```

---

**on plunkr**:

```
/*!
 * ui-grid - v3.0.0-rc.21-aa56355 - 2015-05-06
 * Copyright (c) 2015 ; License: MIT 
 */
```